# Summation of all $n^2$ remainder given special condition

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Please help on this problem. It is from USAMTS. The contest ended today.

Let $n$ be a positive integer. For integers $a, b$ with $0 \leq a,b \leq n-1$, let $r_n(a,b)$ denote the remainder when $ab$ is divided by $n$ if $S_n$ denotes the sum of all $n^2$ remainders $r_n(a,b)$, prove that $$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt n} \leq \frac{S_n}{n^3} \leq \frac {1}{2}.$$

So far, I have determined that for $S_n$, prime numbers are the upper bound to the expression in the middle for the inequality. For prime numbers, the expression for $S_n$ can be given $\frac{n*(n-1)^2}{2}$. 
Also, use of square root in left hand side implies that the lower bound is square number, but I can't find an expression for that. There are many variables as to whether the square number is even or odd, the number of factors, etc. Is there a simpler way to find the lower bound equation?

Hello, I have made a little more progress. I have determined that even squares are the ones that have the lower bound. However, I still can't seem to find an expression for the summation of the remainders for the even square.

Thank! :)

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3393860/remainders-number-theory-question-summation-of-all-remainders).

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, I am new user. I'll edit to include some of my work to differentiate from that question.